# Sitecore login is not working

Tags: login

We created a new Sitecore environment on Azure, we are facing a problem with a login on the CM server

1. When we enter `https://cmserver/sitecore/login` it gets redirected to `https://siserver/Account/Login`
2. After we enter the username password below things we can see in-network and the last call always timed out
   [image]

It seems below Url is not working `/identity/externallogincallback?ReturnUrl=&sc_site=shell&authenticationSource=Default`

We checked all the configurations but we are not able to identify the issue.

Comment: Can you copy full urls or all the requests?

Comment: URL are as below
https://cmserver/sitecore/login redirected 302 to
https://siserver/connect/authorize/callback
Post redirect to https://siserver/identity/signin and then last one is 
https://cmserver/identity/externallogincallback

Comment: @MohdKashif  is this resolved ? what is the solution?